# native XML Database: eXist or Sedna?

Tags: xml, database

I'm trying to decide on which native XML database to choose: eXist or Sedna (both are open source)

I'm using cakePHP, Ajax and WAMP for my website.

I will be using the XML database only for reporting purpose coz' i'm having some semi structured data which cannot be stored in MYSQL.

Which one is well documented?
Which one is easier to learn?
which one has better community support such as forums, etc..? 
What are the advantages and disadvantages of both of them?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Also try [BaseX](http://www.basex.org), offering a very helpful mailing list and wiki documentation.